# Is dice stat rolling still legal in the Adventurer's League?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, ability-scores, dnd-adventurers-league

I was playing a good old one-off campaign tonight, and will be playing the same character through adventure league. I was playing a half-elf sorcerer, and my charisma modifier came into effect. I had rolled my stats, in the way it describes in the second chapter of the 5e handbook, and had gotten lucky with a 17. Half-elf adds two to that (19) and my proficiency bonus made it out to be +6. My DM told me promptly that there was no rolling involved with stats, and that it should be a +5.

This bugged me, so I stared at the page for 5-6 minutes, trying to find the lie.
It says something along the lines of roll 4d6, and don't count the lowest number, and then rinse and repeat for 5 more numbers, and those are your stats.

Is this system still legal in adventure league?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. The [dungeons-and-dragons] tag is for questions spanning multiple editions; the [dnd-5e] tag is sufficient here.

Comment: I don't think you add your proficiency bonus to stat rolls either way.

Comment: I don't think he did

Comment: @PremierBromanov Yeah, this didn't happen in character creation: "I was playing a half-elf sorcerer, and my charisma modifier came into effect." I'm guessing it was a skill check.

Answer (score 21):

The Adventurer's League Player's Guide (available [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/events/adventurers-league-resources)) states which rules are allowed in Adventurer's League play.

> - D&D *Basic Rules* (all rules except rolling ability scores and hit points, rolling for starting wealth, some alignment restrictions)
> - D&D *Player's Handbook* (all rules except rolling ability scores and hit points, some alignment restrictions)

So while rolling ability scores is still a legal rule in D&D, it's not allowed in D&D Adventurer's League play.

Answer (score 9):

The [Adventurers League player information page](http://dnd.wizards.com/playevents/players) says:

> CREATING A CHARACTER
>
> Character creation is easy in the D&D Adventurers League. Check out the D&D Adventurers League Player’s Guide or Quickstart Guide for more information. Otherwise, follow these steps.
>
> - Choose a story origin. [...]
> - Choose a race. [...]
> - Choose a class. [...]
> - Determine ability scores. **You don’t roll for ability scores; instead use either the standard set (15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8) or customize your scores as listed in the Player’s Handbook.**
> - Describe your character. [...]
> - Choose equipment. [...]

There are other restrictions on character creation as well - consult that page (or the Players Guide or Quickstart Guide linked from that page) to make sure you meet all other requirements.